# Secondary DNS server preferred over primary on iOS

Tags: unix, dns, ios

I have created a local DNS server using BIND9. It is just a simple DNS server that forwards queries to 1.1.1.1. When I use this as the only manual DNS server on my iOS device, it works fine. However when I add a secondary DNS server such as 8.8.8.8 as a failover, the secondary server always gets preferred. I read that this could be because of iOS preferring servers that support DoH/DoT, but could this actually be the case if I am using an IP address (8.8.8.8) instead of a domain name. I thought DoT/DoH servers required clients to use their domain name. Has someone else encountered this issue and been successful in resolving it?

When looking at the logs for my DNS server, the only queries that get made are:

```
_dns.resolver.arpa
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the DNS settings on the iPhone? Also, why do you bring up DoT/H, is any of the systems involved using this?

Comment: There's an [automatic DoH discovery scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/id/draft-pauly-add-resolver-discovery-00.html) which is mentioned on https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/add/MbOOWPVHRHM_wvbKhfHuzUTwimI/ as implemented in then-beta OS (that's over three years ago, so probably either on release version by now or dropped entirely), DoT discovery is even easier, just send a DoT query to the IP and accept the response.

Comment: Try confirm first if your device indeed prefer DoH/DoT by setting the secondary as 1.1.1.1, and then visit 1.1.1.1/help which will tell you what protocol is being used

Comment: @nohillside it is literally my server ip address first and then 8.8.8.8 second. Nothing else to it

Comment: @Martheen visiting 1.1.1.1/help shows this: Using DNS over TLS(DoT): Yes. So it looks like iOS is preferring DoT/DoH. So how can I modify my BIND9 server to accept DoT queries so that it can be the preferred server on iOS?

Comment: Either https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735368/how-to-use-dns-over-tls-with-bind9-forwarders or https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-as-dot-doh-gateway/#Deploying-a-Simple-DoT-DNS-Gateway

Comment: @Martheen there is no domain associated with my server so would this still be possible? Or do I need a domain to then generate SSL certs and then I can still use IP address in DNS settings instead of domain?

Comment: SSL certs always require a domain.

Comment: What about if my DNS server was a forwarder to say 1.1.1.1. Would I still need a domain or can I use 1.1.1.1’s cert instead?

Comment: If you forward to the plain DNS over UDP 53, then it means you're doing TLS termination and you need a domain. You'd have to forward port 853 as is to 1.1.1.1:853 without TLS termination, either using iptables or other solution.

Comment: @Martheen so if I simply open port 853 and forward it to 1.1.1.1:853, that gets around my server needing a domain or a SSL cert?

Comment: That depends on how the iOS client verify the cert though. 1.1.1.1 is a special case because the cert actually also contain 1.1.1.1 (the IP) as valid name, not just the domain. I'm not sure what iOS client will do when it receive a valid, CA signed cert for 1.1.1.1 but through different IP. Personally I just have AdGuard Home installed locally with a valid cert for DoT & DoH and explicitly install a config to use them.

Comment: It's my understanding that specifying two DNS servers doesn't typically make the first the primary and a second a fallback, but instead means that either can be queried at the OS's discretion. I believe iOS and macOS both follow this convention.